# Spring boot multi module - child module resource registration issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring boot multi module(POM) Issue, Not registering child module requestmapping resources.

```
Root module
   module1
         M1Controller.java - ("/articles")
   module2 
         M2Controller.java



mvn spring-boot:run
```

/articles resources not registered

Can someone help me or share already existing github example?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). **Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.**

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the M2Controller.java is also included in the component-scan of the M1Controller's Application.  If not you have to include it.

Forexample:

1. if M1Controller is in the package -> in.chn.package1.controllers and your main-application "Application1" is in the package -> in.chn.package1
2. if M2Controller is in the package -> in.chn.package2 then the "Application1" by default will not scan this package and as a result the controller M2Controller will not get registered.

To avoid this problem, you can either set the property scanBasePackages in the @SpringBootApplication or attach the @ComponentScan annotation.

Comment: I tried above solution, it works only If you are in different package with same POM project.
But in my case I created multiple POM (multi pom project).

Comment: Is it not possible to create an artifact for one Module and add as a dependency to another Module.?  We did the same for our project and it worked.